# Не работает ComboBox в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Делаю приложение на JavaFx и хотел сделать выпадающий список, но никак не могу заставить его работать. Выглядит просто как кнопка при нажатии которой появляется одна пустая строка из списка. Я делаю это вот так

```
@FXML
private ComboBox ComboBoxCountry;

@FXML
void initialize() {
ObservableList countries = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Украина", "Россия", "Польша", "Германия", "Франция","Испания","Литва","Португалия");
ComboBoxCountry = new ComboBox(countries);
}
```

Но код дает ноль реакции.
Причем я пробовал делать через стартовое окно ( вообще оно у меня таковым не является) и тогда все работает:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
ObservableList langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Java", "JavaScript", "C#", "Python");
ComboBox langsComboBox = new ComboBox(langs);
Scene scene = new Scene(langsComboBox);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
```

Comment: `ComboBoxCountry.getItems().addAll(countries)` - Вот так надо добавлять элементы.

Comment: У вас при входе в метод `initialize` поле `ComboBoxCountry` уже инициализировано и привязано к сцене. Вы это поле заменяете новым объектом, которого нет на экране.